# Explain a step in the proof that if $f(x)/x^2 \in L^1(0,1)$ and $\sum\limits_na_n=1$ then $\sum\limits_nf(a_nx)$ converges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

My question comes from, but is not, the solution to this problem:

> Let $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} \in L^1(0,1)$ and $a_1,a_2,...$ be positive
>   reals such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = 1$. Show that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)$$ converges a.e on $(0,1)$.

My professor began by considering the problem under the weighted lebesgue measure 
as 
$$\int_0^1\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)\right|\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
and showed that this was finite, and then stated that...

> ...since the result holds for the weighted measure, it must also hold for the standard Lebesgue measure.

I am not really sure how to verify this statement, since I have never seen any result on weighted measures or their relation to the original measure.

> Why exactly is the last highlighted statement above, true?

Comment: Your Professor was right see the answer below

Comment: Consider the function $$g(x)=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)\right|$$ If I understand you correctly, you are asking why the finiteness of $$\int_0^1g(x)\frac{dx}{x^2}$$ implies the finiteness of $$\int_0^1g(x)dx$$ is this correct? If this is, then note that, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $$0\leqslant g(x)\leqslant\frac{g(x)}{x^2}$$ hence this implication seems rather direct, no?

Comment: @Did Right! I agree that the implication is direct when phrased like that, but I guess the confusion came in the phrasing of the problem in terms of the "weighted " measure, which I am unfamiliar with. But it seems it was rather straight forward, but I very much appreciate people fleshing out the details.

Comment: there is $N$ s.t, $0\le a_n<1~ n\ge N$  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)| =\sum_{n=1}^{N} f(a_nx)|+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)| $.  $$\int_0^1|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)|\frac{dx}{x^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1|f(a_nx)|\frac{dx}{x^2}   = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n  \int_0^{a_n}|f(u)|\frac{du}{u^2}\\ \le  \left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \right] \left[\int_0^{1}|f(u)|\frac{du}{u^2}\right] <\infty $$Thus we obtain $\int_0^1|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(a_nx)|\frac{dx}{x^2} <\infty \implies\frac{1}{x^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |f(a_nx)|<\infty~~a.e$ So does $x\mapsto\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(a_nx)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the measure defined on Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $(0,1)$ by
$$
\mu(A) := \int_A \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx,
\qquad A\subset (0,1)\ \text{measurable}.
$$ 
(Observe that you may have $\mu(A) = +\infty$.)

Since $m(A) \leq \mu(A)$ (being $m$ the Lebesgue measure), then $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $m(A)=0$.
Hence, if the series converges for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in (0,1)$, then it converges also for $m$-a.e. $x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? Is there anything about it that is incorrect?

Comment: I think the answer is correct. Moreover, it addresses your question about the comparison of the measures, without any reference to the specific problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, a rather unwarranted downvote.

Answer (score 1):

So $a_{n}\leq 1$ for all $n$. Consider $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\int_{0}^{1}|f(a_{n}x)|\dfrac{dx}{x^{2}}$, a change of variable $y=a_{n}x$ leads to $\displaystyle\sum_{n}a_{n}\int_{0}^{a_{n}}|f(y)|\dfrac{dy}{y^{2}}\leq\displaystyle\sum_{n}a_{n}\int_{0}^{1}|f(y)|\dfrac{dy}{y^{2}}<\infty$, but $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\int_{0}^{1}|f(a_{n}x)|\dfrac{dx}{x^{2}}=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n}|f(a_{n}x)|\dfrac{dx}{x^{2}}$, so $\displaystyle\sum_{n}|f(a_{n}x)|<\infty$ a.e. $\dfrac{dx}{x^{2}}$ on $(0,1)$, it also implies a.e. on $(0,1)$ since for measurable $A\subseteq (0,1)$, we have for Lebesgue measure $\mu$,  $\mu(A)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{A}dx=\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}\chi_{A}\dfrac{dx}{x^{2}}\leq\int_{0}^{1}\chi_{A}\dfrac{dx}{x^{2}}$.